# PHP get the last xx bytes of a text file?

Tags: php, file, search

I have some text files that are very large - 100MB each that contain a single-line string (just 1 line). I want to extract the last xx bytes / characters from each of them. I know how to do this by reading them in a string and then searching by strpos() or substr() but that would require a large chunk of the RAM which isn't desirable for such a small action.

Is there any other way I can just extract, say, the last 50 bytes / characters of the text file in PHP before executing the search?

Thank you!

Comment: you could look into using https://code.google.com/p/php-tail/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php):

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.txt', 'r');
fseek($fp, -50, SEEK_END); // It needs to be negative
$data = fgets($fp, 50);
```

Comment: what you've got there is correct; the number needs to be negative: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php

Comment: Tip: `fgets()` only reads till the end of line, if you need multiple lines, use `fread($fp, bytes)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) by playing with the fourth parameter `offset`.

**PHP 7.1.0 onward:**

In PHP 7.1.0 the fourth parameter `offset` can be negative.

```php
// only negative seek if it "lands" inside the file or false will be returned
if (filesize($filename) > 50) {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename, false, null, -50);
}
else {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
}
```

**Pre PHP 7.1.0:**

```php
$fsz = filesize($filename);
// only negative seek if it "lands" inside the file or false will be returned
if ($fsz > 50) {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename, false, null, $fsz - 50);
}
else {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
}
```

Comment: This is quite ineffective on large files (e.g. 100 MB of logs), since it loads entire file content into memory thus potentially causing application crash.

Comment: @lubosdz I don't think it is. I don't know the internal mechanics of file_get_contents, but if you pass the parameters to only seek and load last bytes, I expect it not to load the entire file into memory in the process.

Comment: Yes, it does load whole file into memory.  If you set memory limit 128 MB and try to read last bytes from 300 MB file it will crash with `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 305043256 bytes)`.

Comment: That's sad... poor design @lubosdz